# Is there a Vim plugin for Highlighting Hex, Rgb, Colors

Tags: vim, plugins

I've been settling myself into Vim these days, I kind of like the HexHighlight Plugin, But I kind of need something that's even better, for example highlighting color names, Hex Codes, rgb color etc. And yeah I do need the text to be visble, contrary to HexHighlight

Comment: If you didn't understand what I said, just look at this [video](http://youtu.be/knKz7_Yz5Nw?t=3m12s) and navigate to the end

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I use a fork of css_color, [vim-css-color](https://github.com/ap/vim-css-color) which claims to fix a few of its shortcomings (mainly speed improvements).

Comment: It also supports more filetypes, works well in Neovim, and supports truecolor in truecolor-capable terminals in both Vim with the terminal truecolor patch and Neovim. It’s actively maintained, while the original hasn’t seen any commits in years.

Comment: Great plugin. I had to `set termguicolors` to get the colors right.

Answer (score 7):

Kind of late to the party, but I would mention that [Colorizer](https://github.com/chrisbra/Colorizer) is a good alternative to [vim_css_color](https://github.com/ap/vim-css-color).

Especially for those who intend to use it for filetypes which the latter does not support; i.e. personal dotfiles which do not rely on Xresources.

Comment: Not a bad thing to be late. This question is 9 years old, nice to give an updated answer

Answer (score 5):

You mean like this plugin: [css_color](https://github.com/skammer/vim-css-color) ?

Comment: Doesn't work for me though, ( On gVim - Ubuntu - 11.10 Beta 1 )

Comment: If this isn't a problem in your configuration (like a gvim that misses too many features, or that is run in cp mode), you should open an issue on its tracker.

Comment: Compatible mode (with plain old vanilla vi) `:h 'cp'`

Comment: This plugin is abandoned, and it slows down Vim startup noticeably. [I have been actively maintaining an improved new version for several years](https://github.com/ap/vim-css-color), also mentioned [in Ullullu’s answer](#27045088), which is much faster and has various added features including support for Neovim and terminal truecolor.